# Simple STM32F0 blink program

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, cortex-m

I try to make a simple blink program for STM32F030F4 (which probably will be identical for whole STM32F0 family). I try to avoid using HAL and setting up anything unnecessary, and I can't make it work.

Hardware and toolchain are working fine, the problem seems to be in the program itself.

Here is the code:

```
/*Include definitions for core and peripheral registers*/
#include <core_cm0.h>
#include <stm32f030x6.h>

/*This function launches first after reset*/
void SystemInit (void)
{
    RCC   -> AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOAEN;   //Enable clock for IO port A
    GPIOA -> MODER  |= GPIO_MODER_MODER4_0;  //A4 to Push-Pull
}

/*Simple delay procedure*/
void wait (int x)
{
    while (x--);                             //Delay by wasting cycles
}

/*Launches right after SystemInit()*/
int main (void)
{
    while (1)                                //Repeat forever
    {
        GPIOA -> BSRR = GPIO_BSRR_BS_4;     //Set A4 to HIGH
        wait(10000);                         //Waste 1e4 cycles
        GPIOA -> BSRR = GPIO_BSRR_BR_4;     //Set A4 to LOW
        wait(10000);                         //Waste again.
    }
}
```

What am I probably missing?

Comment: If you compile that with gcc with optimisations switched on (e.g. `-Os`) then the optimiser will completely remove your `wait()` calls because they have no effect. It's a fool's errand to try to do cycle-accurate delays in code, even assembly code. Use `SysTick` to do accurate timing delays.

Comment: @AndyBrown Thanks for the comment, but that's not it. I do not use `-Os` flags for gcc with this program. Yes, it is quite a cruft, but I did it intentionally for this one, so I don't have to setup `SysTick` too. I wonder if I did not setup something necessary.

Comment: so what is or isnt it doing?  most definitely do not do the wait like that unless perhaps it is in a separately compiled file.  better yet make a simple asm function that simply returns and call that once per loop while(x) bounce(x);  that gets past those problems.   if you dont believe us then show the disassembly of the above and we can walk through it.

Comment: if your led is "glowing" but not blinking then it is most likely the wait as you have implemented it.  if the led is not on at all then it is something else.  are you sure system init is called before main and you should call it from main?

Comment: Thanks, @dwelch, you was almost on point with your last comment. The led was not glowing at all since it was pulled to the ground by the pin. The program itself works fine, and the problem was with messed-up toolchain, wich works inconsistently. In my case, the `SystemInit()` is called, but the `main()` is not. And if I call latter from former, it works, ugh. I am not familiar with depths of compilation process, and suspect messed linker script, which I'm investigating now.

Comment: I think that register BSRR is not for reading. so, replace `|=` with `=` only. Also function wait() will be optimized and not called.

Comment: @vlk, you're right, `BSRR` is read-only. I edited the code. However, `wait`, at least in my case, is not optimized unless I pass `-O` to gcc, so I leave it as it is for now.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something here will help, bare metal not using their tools at all, any (well many/most?) gnu arm toolchain should work.

the disassembler is your friend, you want to go bare metal and not use their sandbox or tools then to get it booted you need to disassemble to save time in debugging.

this blinks pa4 and 5, you can adjust as needed.

blinker01.c

```
void PUT32 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
unsigned int GET32 ( unsigned int );
void dummy ( unsigned int );

#define GPIOABASE 0x48000000
#define RCCBASE 0x40021000

int notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    unsigned int rx;

    ra=GET32(RCCBASE+0x14);
    ra|=1<<17; //enable port a
    PUT32(RCCBASE+0x14,ra);
    //moder
    ra=GET32(GPIOABASE+0x00);
    ra&=~(3<<8); //PA4
    ra&=~(3<<10); //PA5
    ra|=1<<8; //PA4
    ra|=1<<10; //PA5
    PUT32(GPIOABASE+0x00,ra);
    //OTYPER
    ra=GET32(GPIOABASE+0x04);
    ra&=~(1<<4); //PA4
    ra&=~(1<<5); //PA5
    PUT32(GPIOABASE+0x04,ra);
    //ospeedr
    ra=GET32(GPIOABASE+0x08);
    ra|=3<<8; //PA4
    ra|=3<<10; //PA5
    PUT32(GPIOABASE+0x08,ra);
    //pupdr
    ra=GET32(GPIOABASE+0x0C);
    ra&=~(3<<8); //PA4
    ra&=~(3<<10); //PA5
    PUT32(GPIOABASE+0x0C,ra);

    for(rx=0;;rx++)
    {
        PUT32(GPIOABASE+0x18,(1<<5)|(1<<4));
        for(ra=0;ra<200000;ra++) dummy(ra);
        PUT32(GPIOABASE+0x18,(1<<(5+16))|(1<<(4+16)));
        for(ra=0;ra<200000;ra++) dummy(ra);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

flash.s

```
;@-----------------------
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb
;@-----------------------

.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
stacktop: .word 0x20001000
.word reset
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang

.thumb_func
reset:
    bl notmain
    b hang
.thumb_func
hang:   b .
;@-----------------------
.align
;@-----------------------
.thumb_func
.globl PUT16
PUT16:
    strh r1,[r0]
    bx lr
;@-----------------------
.thumb_func
.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr
;@-----------------------
.thumb_func
.globl GET32
GET32:
    ldr r0,[r0]
    bx lr
;@-----------------------
.thumb_func
.globl dummy
dummy:
    bx lr
;@-----------------------
.end
;@-----------------------
```

sram.s

```
;@-----------------------
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb
;@-----------------------
.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
    ldr r0,stacktop
    mov sp,r0
    bl notmain
    b hang
.thumb_func
hang:   b .
;@-----------------------
.align
stacktop: .word 0x20001000
;@-----------------------
.thumb_func
.globl PUT16
PUT16:
    strh r1,[r0]
    bx lr
;@-----------------------
.thumb_func
.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr
;@-----------------------
.thumb_func
.globl GET32
GET32:
    ldr r0,[r0]
    bx lr
;@-----------------------
.thumb_func
.globl dummy
dummy:
    bx lr
;@-----------------------
.end
;@-----------------------
```

flash.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > ram
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

sram.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > ram
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

Makefile  gnu tools or clang+llvm+gnu ld.

replace ARMGNU with whatever your cross compiler is.

```
ARMGNU = arm-none-eabi
#ARMGNU = arm-linux-gnueabi

AOPS = --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m0
COPS = -Wall -Werror -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding  -mcpu=cortex-m0

LOPS = -Wall -m32 -emit-llvm -target arm-none-eabi -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb
LLCOPS = -march=thumb -mcpu=cortex-m0
#LLCOPS = -mcpu=cortex-m0
COPS = -Wall  -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding
OOPS = -std-compile-opts

gcc : blinker01.gcc.thumb.flash.bin blinker01.gcc.thumb.sram.bin

all : gcc clang

clang : blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.flash.bin blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.flash.bin blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.sram.bin blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.sram.bin 

clean:
    rm -f *.bin
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.elf
    rm -f *.list
    rm -f *.bc
    rm -f *.opt.s
    rm -f *.norm.s

#---------------------------------

flash.o : flash.s
    $(ARMGNU)-as $(AOPS) flash.s -o flash.o

sram.o : sram.s
    $(ARMGNU)-as $(AOPS) sram.s -o sram.o

blinker01.gcc.thumb.o : blinker01.c
    $(ARMGNU)-gcc $(COPS) -mthumb -c blinker01.c -o blinker01.gcc.thumb.o

blinker01.gcc.thumb.flash.bin : flash.ld flash.o blinker01.gcc.thumb.o
    $(ARMGNU)-ld -o blinker01.gcc.thumb.flash.elf -T flash.ld flash.o blinker01.gcc.thumb.o
    $(ARMGNU)-objdump -D blinker01.gcc.thumb.flash.elf > blinker01.gcc.thumb.flash.list
    $(ARMGNU)-objcopy blinker01.gcc.thumb.flash.elf blinker01.gcc.thumb.flash.bin -O binary

blinker01.gcc.thumb.sram.bin : sram.ld sram.o blinker01.gcc.thumb.o
    $(ARMGNU)-ld -o blinker01.gcc.thumb.sram.elf -T sram.ld sram.o blinker01.gcc.thumb.o
    $(ARMGNU)-objdump -D blinker01.gcc.thumb.sram.elf > blinker01.gcc.thumb.sram.list
    $(ARMGNU)-objcopy blinker01.gcc.thumb.sram.elf blinker01.gcc.thumb.sram.bin -O binary

#---------------------------------

blinker01.clang.bc : blinker01.c
    clang $(LOPS) -c blinker01.c -o blinker01.clang.bc

blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.flash.bin : flash.ld flash.o blinker01.clang.bc
    #llc $(LLCOPS) blinker01.clang.bc -o blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.s
    #$(ARMGNU)-as $(AOPS) blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.s -o blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.o
    llc $(LLCOPS) blinker01.clang.bc -filetype=obj -o blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.o
    $(ARMGNU)-ld -o blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.flash.elf -T flash.ld flash.o blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.o
    $(ARMGNU)-objdump -D blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.flash.elf > blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.flash.list
    $(ARMGNU)-objcopy blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.flash.elf blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.flash.bin -O binary

blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.flash.bin : flash.ld flash.o blinker01.clang.bc
    opt $(OOPS) blinker01.clang.bc -o blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.bc
    #llc $(LLCOPS) blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.bc -o blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.s
    #$(ARMGNU)-as $(AOPS) blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.s -o blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.o
    llc $(LLCOPS) blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.bc -filetype=obj -o blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.o
    $(ARMGNU)-ld -o blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.flash.elf -T flash.ld flash.o blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.o
    $(ARMGNU)-objdump -D blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.flash.elf > blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.flash.list
    $(ARMGNU)-objcopy blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.flash.elf blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.flash.bin -O binary


blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.sram.bin : sram.ld sram.o blinker01.clang.bc
    #llc $(LLCOPS) blinker01.clang.bc -o blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.s
    #$(ARMGNU)-as $(AOPS) blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.s -o blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.o
    llc $(LLCOPS) blinker01.clang.bc -filetype=obj -o blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.o
    $(ARMGNU)-ld -o blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.sram.elf -T sram.ld sram.o blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.o
    $(ARMGNU)-objdump -D blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.sram.elf > blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.sram.list
    $(ARMGNU)-objcopy blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.sram.elf blinker01.clang.thumb.norm.sram.bin -O binary

blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.sram.bin : sram.ld sram.o blinker01.clang.bc
    opt $(OOPS) blinker01.clang.bc -o blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.bc
    #llc $(LLCOPS) blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.bc -o blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.s
    #$(ARMGNU)-as $(AOPS) blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.s -o blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.o
    llc $(LLCOPS) blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.bc -filetype=obj -o blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.o
    $(ARMGNU)-ld -o blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.sram.elf -T sram.ld sram.o blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.o
    $(ARMGNU)-objdump -D blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.sram.elf > blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.sram.list
    $(ARMGNU)-objcopy blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.sram.elf blinker01.clang.thumb.opt.sram.bin -O binary
```

blinks pa4 and 5 on an stm32f0. because of different startup conditions I have different bootstrap code, arguably you could use the same one and just resume from an offset for running from sram (jtag).

flash version disassembly careful here to inspect that the first item is the stack pointer load value, then the addresses I think have to be odd (thumb mode) but not sure, could easily test that.  the lsbit is stripped when used so 0x08000040 is the reset vector and that is what we see in the disassembly, the sp was loaded by the logic so we can go right to notmain (just a habit from an old toolchain that would add junk if it saw a function named main)

```
08000000 <_start>:
 8000000:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
 8000004:   08000041    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r6}
 8000008:   08000047    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r2, r6}
 800000c:   08000047    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r2, r6}
 8000010:   08000047    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r2, r6}
 8000014:   08000047    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r2, r6}
 8000018:   08000047    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r2, r6}
 800001c:   08000047    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r2, r6}
 8000020:   08000047    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r2, r6}
 8000024:   08000047    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r2, r6}
 8000028:   08000047    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r2, r6}
 800002c:   08000047    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r2, r6}
 8000030:   08000047    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r2, r6}
 8000034:   08000047    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r2, r6}
 8000038:   08000047    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r2, r6}
 800003c:   08000047    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r2, r6}

08000040 <reset>:
 8000040:   f000 f80a   bl  8000058 <notmain>
 8000044:   e7ff        b.n 8000046 <hang>

08000046 <hang>:
 8000046:   e7fe        b.n 8000046 <hang>

08000048 <PUT16>:
 8000048:   8001        strh    r1, [r0, #0]
 800004a:   4770        bx  lr

0800004c <PUT32>:
 800004c:   6001        str r1, [r0, #0]
 800004e:   4770        bx  lr

08000050 <GET32>:
 8000050:   6800        ldr r0, [r0, #0]
 8000052:   4770        bx  lr

08000054 <dummy>:
 8000054:   4770        bx  lr
 8000056:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)

08000058 <notmain>:
 8000058:   b570        push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
 800005a:   4824        ldr r0, [pc, #144]  ; (80000ec <notmain+0x94>)
 800005c:   f7ff fff8   bl  8000050 <GET32>
 8000060:   2180        movs    r1, #128    ; 0x80
 8000062:   0289        lsls    r1, r1, #10
 8000064:   4301        orrs    r1, r0
 8000066:   4821        ldr r0, [pc, #132]  ; (80000ec <notmain+0x94>)
 8000068:   f7ff fff0   bl  800004c <PUT32>
 800006c:   2090        movs    r0, #144    ; 0x90
 800006e:   05c0        lsls    r0, r0, #23
 8000070:   f7ff ffee   bl  8000050 <GET32>
 8000074:   21a0        movs    r1, #160    ; 0xa0
 8000076:   4c1e        ldr r4, [pc, #120]  ; (80000f0 <notmain+0x98>)
 8000078:   00c9        lsls    r1, r1, #3
 800007a:   4020        ands    r0, r4
 800007c:   4301        orrs    r1, r0
 800007e:   2090        movs    r0, #144    ; 0x90
 8000080:   05c0        lsls    r0, r0, #23
 8000082:   f7ff ffe3   bl  800004c <PUT32>
 8000086:   481b        ldr r0, [pc, #108]  ; (80000f4 <notmain+0x9c>)
 8000088:   f7ff ffe2   bl  8000050 <GET32>
 800008c:   2330        movs    r3, #48 ; 0x30
 800008e:   0001        movs    r1, r0
 8000090:   4818        ldr r0, [pc, #96]   ; (80000f4 <notmain+0x9c>)
 8000092:   4399        bics    r1, r3
 8000094:   f7ff ffda   bl  800004c <PUT32>
 8000098:   4817        ldr r0, [pc, #92]   ; (80000f8 <notmain+0xa0>)
 800009a:   f7ff ffd9   bl  8000050 <GET32>
 800009e:   21f0        movs    r1, #240    ; 0xf0
 80000a0:   0109        lsls    r1, r1, #4
 80000a2:   4301        orrs    r1, r0
 80000a4:   4814        ldr r0, [pc, #80]   ; (80000f8 <notmain+0xa0>)
 80000a6:   f7ff ffd1   bl  800004c <PUT32>
 80000aa:   4814        ldr r0, [pc, #80]   ; (80000fc <notmain+0xa4>)
 80000ac:   f7ff ffd0   bl  8000050 <GET32>
 80000b0:   0001        movs    r1, r0
 80000b2:   4812        ldr r0, [pc, #72]   ; (80000fc <notmain+0xa4>)
 80000b4:   4021        ands    r1, r4
 80000b6:   f7ff ffc9   bl  800004c <PUT32>
 80000ba:   4d11        ldr r5, [pc, #68]   ; (8000100 <notmain+0xa8>)
 80000bc:   2130        movs    r1, #48 ; 0x30
 80000be:   4811        ldr r0, [pc, #68]   ; (8000104 <notmain+0xac>)
 80000c0:   f7ff ffc4   bl  800004c <PUT32>
 80000c4:   2400        movs    r4, #0
 80000c6:   0020        movs    r0, r4
 80000c8:   3401        adds    r4, #1
 80000ca:   f7ff ffc3   bl  8000054 <dummy>
 80000ce:   42ac        cmp r4, r5
 80000d0:   d1f9        bne.n   80000c6 <notmain+0x6e>
 80000d2:   21c0        movs    r1, #192    ; 0xc0
 80000d4:   480b        ldr r0, [pc, #44]   ; (8000104 <notmain+0xac>)
 80000d6:   0389        lsls    r1, r1, #14
 80000d8:   f7ff ffb8   bl  800004c <PUT32>
 80000dc:   2400        movs    r4, #0
 80000de:   0020        movs    r0, r4
 80000e0:   3401        adds    r4, #1
 80000e2:   f7ff ffb7   bl  8000054 <dummy>
 80000e6:   42ac        cmp r4, r5
 80000e8:   d1f9        bne.n   80000de <notmain+0x86>
 80000ea:   e7e7        b.n 80000bc <notmain+0x64>
 80000ec:   40021014    andmi   r1, r2, r4, lsl r0
 80000f0:   fffff0ff            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0xfffff0ff
 80000f4:   48000004    stmdami r0, {r2}
 80000f8:   48000008    stmdami r0, {r3}
 80000fc:   4800000c    stmdami r0, {r2, r3}
 8000100:   00030d40    andeq   r0, r3, r0, asr #26
 8000104:   48000018    stmdami r0, {r3, r4}
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks like a lot to learn, I think I will be studying your answer for a while.